# Как сделать APK файл?

Tags: android, apk

Как сделать APK файл, если у меня есть сам проект?

Comment: А какое отношение эти "папки" и "зип файл" имеют к Андроид-приложениям?

Answer (score 2):

1. Зайдите в **Android Studio**.
2. Найдите на верхней панели вкладку **Build**.
3. Нажмите на вкладку **Build**
4. Из выпадающего списка найдите **Build APK(s)**.
5. Нажмите на вкладку **Build APK(s)**.
6. После в нижнем правом углу появится сообщение, найдите слово **locate**.
7. Нажмите на слово **locate**
8. Вы создали и нашли где находится **APK** файл. Поздравляю!!!

   Фотографии как это выглядит (**MAC OS**):
   [image: build]
   [image: locate]

Comment: вообще для создания плноценного APK нужен пункт *Generate Signed APK*. В вашем случае при создании релизной сборки мы получим неподписанный APK или подписанный отладочным ключом при сборке debug

Comment: @pavlofff да, я думал об этом. Но подумал так как в вопросе не со всем понятно нужно ли подписанное ключом приложение, то написал краткий гайд. Думаю позже отредактирую

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Xl8XIhq
Извиняюсь тут нету Генерации апк(((