# Как сделать apk из проекта с Github?

Tags: android, android-studio

Я бы хотела сделать сделать apk файл из - [ссылка на github](https://github.com/rrkkhd/BookReaderApp)
(если это возможно...)

Этот вопрос уже задавался на stackOverflow - [воть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/815095/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-apk-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB)

но у меня нет этого раздела в build

Как тогда сделать apk из проекта?
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка debug на яндекс диске [тык](https://yadi.sk/d/0B7FLSC5ZaTrMA)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А у вас синхронизация и билд прошли успешно?

Comment: этот проект использует язык программирования kotlin, видимо вам нужно установить плагин поддержки kotlin в Android Studio

Comment: Попробуйте сначала нажать “Make project”, это должно скомпилировать проект, и потом, если пункт build не появится, вы можете в папке с вашим проектом: app\build\outputs найти файл app-debug.apk

Comment: Получилось сделать apk, но оно подписано "app-debug.apk" (так и должно быть?)  и после установки на android при любом нажатии выдает ошибку. Ссылку добавила в конце на яндекс диск

Comment: да, файл так и должен называться, потому что он создан для отладки. Приложение вылетает из-за неправильно написанного кода. Тут уже вопросы к автору этого репозитория

Comment: Хорошо, большое спасибо за помощь